# How to fix the 'no severless pages built' in nextjs deployment using vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, serverless-architecture

I' am trying to deploy my NextJs app. I have been getting the same 2 errors the past few days:

1: // and will just error later on
2: Error: No serverless pages were built. Learn More: https://err.sh/vercel/vercel/now-next-no-serverless-pages-built
I have got no clue on how to fix both of them. I would appreciate it if anyone helped

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-dev-portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "bulid": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "now-build": "next build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.19.0"
  }
}
```

The next.config.json file:

```
module.exports = {
    target: "serverless"
}
```

now.json file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{"src":"package.json", "use": "@now/next"}]
}
```

Comment: Any code that you can share?

Comment: I Just put it on @paulogdm

Comment: You don't need the `now.json` nor `target` there. Remove those files and check your project's settings to see if Next.js is set as the framework.

Answer (score 8):

Try this if you're working with newer version of node

Navigate to settings of your project in Vercel dashboard

> [https://vercel.com/[username]/[project]/settings](https://vercel.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Bproject%5D/settings)

#### Follow this process to fix:

1. Scroll down to **Node.js Version** of Search for **Node.js Version** on the page
2. Select a newer version, probably **16x** or **18x** and not **14x**
3. Click the 'SAVE' button
4. Navigate back to **Deployments** [https://vercel.com/[username]/[project]/deployments](https://vercel.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Bproject%5D/deployments)
5. Click the hamburger menu (three dots) in your most recent commit
6. Then click the 'REDEPLOY' button and make sure not to select the cache option

App should build successfully now

> Ensure to replace [username] and [project] with your respective vercel username and vercel project id

Answer (score 2):

For `now.json`: you are using a very old method. Vercel can now detect your framework. Check the announcement in the blog: [Zero Config Deployments](https://vercel.com/blog/zero-config)
.

For `next.config.js` where you are using `target: serverless`, that is also not needed at all. Just remove it if you are deploying to Vercel. For those curious, check https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing for more information on a better solution that replaced `target`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need now.json file. Delete it and try deployment again

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by sentry. Locally the app ran fine, but when built it failed with this error.
When I removed withSentryConfig from the last line modyifing it from:

```
module.exports = withSentryConfig(nextConfig, SentryWebpackPluginOptions)
```

to

```
module.exports = nextConfig
```

It built again on vercel.

I suspect it's caused by a bug in @sentry/nextjs where it does not pass
`pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']` correctly to next.js on build.